# Params in routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I wish to pass a param from my route to my controller, eg.

```
Route::get('/press', array(
    'as'=>'sm-press-browse',
    'uses'=>'SiteManagerController@getPress(param-here)'
));
```

I do not wish to have the param in my url, eg.

```
Route::get('/press/{param-here}', array(
    'as'=>'sm-press-browse',
    'uses'=>'SiteManagerController@getPress'
));
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route is not meant to pass parameter, but to define where parameters will be in the URLs.

Think like this, where will be the `{param-here}` in your second example?

So no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has no built in function but this is possible.
For this, you have to take help of php magic method named __call()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call